# Переменна элементов списка местами

Tags: c++, list

Задача заключается в том, что нужно поменять элементы списка местами. Элементы выбирает пользователь.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct list
{
    int elem;
    struct list* next;
}list;

int main()
{
    list* p = NULL;
    list* temp;
    p = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));


    p->elem = 1;
    p->next = NULL;


    temp = p;


    temp->next = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    temp = temp->next;
    temp->elem = 2;
    temp->next = NULL;


    temp->next = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
    temp = temp->next;
    temp->elem = 3;
    temp->next = NULL;

    

    cout << p->elem << '-' << p->next->elem << '-' << p->next->next->elem << '\n';

    list* udalit = p;
    p = udalit->next;
    delete udalit;

    cout << p->elem << '-' << p->next->elem << '\n';

    return 0;
}```
````